# install phpMyAdmin with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, phpmyadmin

I have a vps (windows server 2019) for hosting my spring boot web application, I use tomcat as web server and Mysql as database manager, and install both of them on my vps,
and now i wanna install phpMyAdmin, but don't know how to install it! for using phpMyAdmin i need to install iis or apache on my vps ? phpMyAdmin does not work with tomcat?
installing 2 web server (tomcat and apache or iis) does not slow down the server ?

i don't know how to deal with this condition,
please help me,
thanks!

Comment: You Also need PHP to run phpMyAdmin. Why not try MySQL
 Workbench instead

Comment: @RiggsFolly Does it have the same efficiency?

Comment: What efficiency. They are both tools to make maintenance of a MySQL Database simpler for the beginner. What are you expecting phpMyAdmin to do?

Comment: @samaz both are GUI clients for managing mysql databases. The big difference is that phpmyadmin can provide remote GUI without the need to open mysql connection up remotely, while mysql workbench requires either direct remote database connection or some kind of a VPN / ssh tunnel into the database server.